# Python recursion list

Tags: python, list, recursion

This is the situation: A list consisting of ids - every one of those Ids can be related to any number (0 to n) other ids, which again can be related to other ids, etc. As a result I want a list of all relations, no matter the "depth".

At least to me this screams recursion but I can't quite wrap my head around how to do it.

```
def dive(rels):
    if dive(rels) == []:
        return rels
    else:
        for item in rels:
            rels.append(getRelation(item))
            rels = list(set(flattenAndClean(rels)))
            return dive(rels)
```

This is my first (not working) attempt, where the function getRelation returns a list of relations of this item and the function flattenAndClean takes nested lists and returns flat ones.

Edit: Example:

```
Items={1:[4,5,6],2:[6,8],3:[],4:[7],5:[],6:[],7:[4],8:[]}
List = [1,2,3]

def getRelation(id):
    return Items[id]

In: dive(List)
Out: [4,5,6,7,8]
```

Comment: You should add an example. Example list and the resultant output.

Comment: It is not clear just what `getRelation` does or what `rels` is. Please show a full, complete example, as in [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). This seems to be a basic problem in graph theory (also called network theory), finding the connected components of a graph. Do a search on those concepts. Are those "relationships" always two-way or can they be one-way?

Comment: Great suggestion thanks, I will try to whip something up! :-)

Comment: Recursion needs base case (you have it when the list is empty) and parameters ``different`` from those you got initially, and you're just passing over same parameters, so it never terminates.

Comment: Continuing dmitryro's point: In (simple, without an accumulator) recursion, eventually you're going to have a line of code like: `return the_result_for_this_element + myself(the_rest_of_the_elements)`.

Comment: This will get a stackoverflow since the first call of `dive(rels)` is `dive(rels)` (with `rels` unaltered).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
def rels(items, L):
    answer = set(L)
    for i in L:
        targs = tuple(t for t in items[i] if t not in L)
        L.extend(targs)
        answer.update(set(targs))
    return answer
```

Output

```
In [29]: rels({1:[4,5,6],2:[6,8],3:[],4:[7],5:[],6:[],7:[4],8:[]}, [1,2,3])
Out[29]: {1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8}
```